# Limit of Sequence of continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 1-nx,&\text{for }x\in[0,1/n]\\
0 ,&\text{for }x \in [1/n,1] 
\end{cases}$$

Then which is correct option?

1.$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }f_n(x)$ defines a continuous function on $[0,1]$.

2.$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }f_n(x)$ exists for all $x\in [0,1]$. $f_n(0)=1$ and  $f_n(1/n)=0$

I think first option is correct but I have no proper justification for that just by looking at the graph of function, $f$ is continuous but again there is a question arises if $f$ is continuous then why $2$ is wrong? Please correct me and help me to understand this problem.

Comment: What is the pointwise limit $f(x)$?

Comment: That means you need to say that pointwise limit does not exist?

Comment: No, it exists. I am asking if you have computed it.

Comment: If I take x=1/2 then $f_n(1/2)=1-n/2  $ for $x\in [0,1/n] $ as n tends to infinity limit does not exist

Comment: @user159480: you interpret wrongly. For $x=\frac12$, $f_1=1-1\cdot\frac12=\frac12, f_2=1-2\cdot\frac12=0$ and for all $n>2, f_n=0$.

Comment: Thanks,I understand my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The function converges pointwise to a discontinuous function which takes the value $1$ when $x$ is $0$ and takes the value $0$ otherwise.

Hence option $2$ is correct and option $1$ is false.

Explanation:

Say $1>x>0$

Then let us see the sequence $f_1(x),f_2(x),f_3(x)\dots$
The terms of this sequence eventually equals to $0$, as for every $x>0$ there exists an integer $N$ such that $1/N<x$, so $f_n(x)=0$ for all $n\geq N$, so the limit is also $0$.
And for $x=1$ the $f_n(x)=1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, hence the sequence converges to $1$.

Hence the limit function $f$ equals $1$ if $x=0$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The function cannot be continuous at $x=0$, because its value is $1$ and the values at all $x>0$ are $0$. (Because for $x>0$, there is always an $n$ such that $1/n<x$).

The option 2. is correct because the limit is defined for all $x$ (as above) and the last two equalities come from the definition.